# find_element_by_xpath(xpath) takes ~17 seconds although implicitly_wait(0) set to 0

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following code takes ~17 seconds to find xpath although xpath is available.
how to reduce time to execute  each built-in selenium webdriver command.?

```
driver.implicitly_wait(0)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

is there way to get the what is the implicitly_wait at given point in time in code

Comment: How did you conclude `code takes ~17 seconds`?

Comment: Is this `driver.find_element_by_xpath` or your customized `find_element_by_xpath`?

Comment: this is driver.find_element_by_xpath

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `driver.implicitly_wait(0)`?

Comment: No chanage in behaviour , resetting implicit wait back to "0" as driver may be taking any random value from code flow for implicitly_wait()

Comment: Can you share the XPath query? And the URL for the page? And the code you used to time the call?

Comment: Ian URL is not accessable from outside. code is just to find xpath of it after upl is open